# Can't find .config on the root

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

[image: there is no .config on my clean ubuntu server]

So this step on the "Ubuntu setup for Plutus Playround" Cant work.

> mkdir ~/.config/nix
> echo 'substituters = https://hydra.iohk.io https://iohk.cachix.org [https://cache.nixos.org/'](https://cache.nixos.org/%27) >> ~/.config/nix/nix.conf
> echo 'trusted-public-keys = hydra.iohk.io:f/Ea+s+dFdN+3Y/G+FDgSq+a5NEWhJGzdjvKNGv0/EQ= iohk.cachix.org-1:DpRUyj7h7V830dp/i6Nti+NEO2/nhblbov/8MW7Rqoo= cache.nixos.org-1:6NCHdD59X431o0gWypbMrAURkbJ16ZPMQFGspcDShjY=' >> ~/.config/nix/nix.conf

what should i do? trying to create a .config folder don't work either.
(my coding and linux level is low)

Comment: If the file does not exist you have to create it. It should work.

Comment: Don't work.. 
mkdir ~/.config/nix
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/cnode/.config/nix’: No such file or directory

Comment: Not sure what directory you are in (folder).  Maybe post back (use pwd).  None the less, you probably don't have the nix.conf file made in /etc/nix directory?  Try this on how to make one: https://www.punkbit.com/hacking/plutus-developer-environment-setup-on-macos-monterey/

Answer (score 2):

It’s because the folder .config does not exist yet, so you cannot create the nested folder nix

So you run this instead

`mkdir -p ~/.config/nix`